# How to oversample time series for time series classification using ADASYN in Python?

Tags: python, oversampling

**I have a dataframe like this:**

[image: screen shot]

Because the label is binary and very imbalanced, I would like to use ADASYN for oversampling.
As you may see, it is actually the time series of 30 days for each user, so it does not make sense when I just use:

```
ada = ADASYN()  
X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X, y)

where X = (feature 1, feature 2) and y = label.
```

Do you have any ideas to handle this problem?